# Document management for private usage

Tags: document-management, dms

For private usage I am looking for a simple document management system (NOT a Web CMS). The requirements are relatively simple :

- Web based
- Free, prefer open-source
- Able to store electronic documents (Word, PDF, ...) and scanned paper documents (in PDF/jpeg/whatever image format)
- OCR support
- Along with some metadata : name of the doc, project/department to which it belongs, author, date, place, some identifiying code, a short description,...
- Using different storage (NAS, Dropbox, WebDAV)

Optional but nice

- Versioning
- Indexing/search inside the word/pdf/text/... documents

I've tried doo for my mac, but it's still to buggy ...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could run Alfresco or Nuxeo locally.  Nuxeo has an OCR module that uses the tesseract OCR engine https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo-platform-ocr.  They both support all of your list including the optional part.

However, these two systems are complex, and require a fair degree of configuration – hence, perhaps couldn't be described as 'simple'.

If you want something simple for Mac OS X, you could try the commercial offering called Paperless https://www.marinersoftware.com/products/paperless/.  I haven't used the latest version, but it looks like they've added OCR support.  This doesn't meet the free preference though!

Comment: thx, I will try Nuxeo, looks like the better tool for me.